# Mobile Renders Incorrectly Azure App Service Blazor Webassembly (ASP.NET Hosted)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, mobile-safari, blazor-webassembly

I published a Blazor Webassembly ASP.NET Core hosted website to Azure App Service and it works as expected on laptop browsers. However, if I navigate to it on mobile (iOS Safari) it seems to only display my Pages and not my MainLayout.Razor file- that is, the  doesn't show. Why is this the case? Thanks

index.html file

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <title>My Blazor App</title>
    <base href="/" />
    <link href="css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/app.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="_content/BlazorContentEditable/BlazorContentEditable.js"></script>
    <link href="manifest.json" rel="manifest" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="512x512" href="icon-512.png" />
</head>

<body>
    <app>Loading...</app>
    <div id="blazor-error-ui">
        An unhandled error has occurred.
        <a href="" class="reload">Reload</a>
        <a class="dismiss"></a>
    </div>
    <script src="_framework/blazor.webassembly.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

App.razor

```cs
<Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly">
    <Found Context="routeData">
        <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)" />
    </Found>
    <NotFound>
        <CascadingAuthenticationState>
            <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                <p>Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
            </LayoutView>
        </CascadingAuthenticationState>
    </NotFound>
</Router>
```

MainLayout.razor

```cs
@inherits LayoutComponentBase

<div class="main">
    <div class="top-row px-4">
        <LoginDisplay />
    </div>

    <div class="content px-4">
        @Body
    </div>
</div>
```

LoginDisplay.razor

```cs
<AuthorizeView>
    <Authorized>
        <h1>Hello, @context.User.Identity.Name!</h1>
        <a href="LogOut">Log out</a>
    </Authorized>
    <NotAuthorized>
        <a href="/">Home</a>
        <a href="Register">Register</a>
        <a href="Login">Log in</a>
    </NotAuthorized>
</AuthorizeView>
```

[image: Screenshot on laptop chrome browser]

[image: Screenshot on mobile safari browser]

First is screenshot on laptop chrome browser. Second is screenshot on mobile safari browser

**EDIT**

Now after playing around with the app.css file a bit, with these settings:

```css
@media (max-width: 767.98px) {
    .main .top-row {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        padding: 5px 0;
    }

    .image {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }

    .main .top-row a, .main .top-row .btn-link {
        display: flex;
        margin-left: 0;
        justify-content: space-between;
        padding: 5px 0;
    }
    
}
```

[image]

The iPhone SE emulator works perfectly when running in dev mode. Yet, publishing it does nothing navigating to it on my phone. It looks exactly the same as before.

Comment: Not entirely clear. The side menu should collapse but there should still be a top-bar with a menu button. Add a screenshot. Also use the F12 tools to run it in a phone-sized browser on your PC.

Comment: I added the screenshots. I had taken out the default side menu in the template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to why the LoginDisplay component wasn't rendering was in fact what Henk mentioned. However, I had to eliminate the entire section that said:

```css
   .main .top-row:not(.auth) {
       display: none;
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

In the default `site.css` (or `app.css`) we have

```
@media (max-width: 767.98px) {
    .main .top-row:not(.auth) {
        display: none;
    }
```

so i guess you should just remove the `.top-row:not(.auth)` part there.

Comment: I took out that part and republished but the top row still doesn't display on safari.

Comment: Always force-refresh after a CSS update (-:  Ctrl+F5 usually.

Comment: Ok your advice seems to be getting me in the right direction, but now I'm getting rather bizarre and inconsistent results. I'll make another post in a bit to explain.

Comment: Check my post again, I added my edits and the results of them.